# Segmentation fault appearing, when using fgets a second time

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, fgets

This is my complete code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#define SEN_LIMITERS ".!?"

int main()
{
char inputexp[256];
char inputString[256];

const char *Limits = SEN_LIMITERS;
char *sentence;

regex_t expression;

char **cont = NULL;
int Words = 0, index;

printf("Please enter the string to analyse: \n");
if(fgets(inputString,255,stdin) != NULL);

printf("Please enter the regular expression :");

if(fgets(inputexp,255,stdin) != NULL);

inputexp[strlen(inputexp)-1] = '\0';

if (regcomp(&expression,inputexp,REG_EXTENDED) != 0) {
    printf("ERROR: Something wrong in the regular expression\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

sentence = strtok_r(inputString,Limits,cont);
while(sentence != NULL){
    printf("%s\n",sentence);

    if (regexec(&expression,sentence,0,NULL,0) == 0) {
        printf("Yes    ");
    } else {
        printf("No   ");
    }

    for (index = 0;sentence[index] != '\0';index++)
    {
        if (sentence[index] == ' ')
            Words++;
    }
    printf("%d words\n",Words);
    Words = 0;

    sentence = strtok_r(inputString,Limits,cont);
}

return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

//stop

For some reason when ever i run it the segmentation fault occurs after the second fgets.

```
Please enter the string to analyse: 
abba and a bee. aah mama mia. there we go again. in the city of miami.
Please enter the regular expression :a[bm].*[ai]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Im really at a loss as to why it is occurring, as the first fgets seems to go through. Im not sure If i should be malloc anything for the same reason as above.

Comment: What is this statement supposed to do? `if(fgets(inputexp,255,stdin) != NULL);`

Comment: You have a crash somewhere.  You need to probably debug it.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

The crash in your program comes from this line:

```
sentence = strtok_r(inputString,Limits,cont);
```

To surpass it, you have to declare `cont` as  `char *` and pass its address to `strtok_r`:

```
sentence = strtok_r(inputString, Limits, &cont);
```

And to avoid endless loop, in `strtok_t` in the `while` statement, you have to change `inputString` to `NULL`, in the way specified in `strtok_r` man page:

> On the first call to strtok_r(), str should point to the string to be
>   parsed, and the value of saveptr is ignored.  In subsequent calls, str
>   should be NULL, and saveptr  should  be
>          unchanged since the previous call.

So the second call to `strtok_r` should be like the following:

```
sentence = strtok_r(NULL, Limits, &cont);
```

---

Another note is about handling `fgets` error cases, which can't be made by just a semicolon `;`, you can do it in similar way to:

```
if (fgets(inputString, 255, stdin) != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while reading input text\n.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```